# In rocksdb Is there any way to know upto what size a file can go in a level?

Tags: rocksdb

I am working on rocksdb,but unable to get an option which can tell me the maximum limit of size file inside a level ? And if once it reaches that maximum size how files gets split in RocksDB?

Answer (score 2):

The option you are looking for is `target_file_size_base` and `target_file_size_multiplier`.

target_file_size_base - configures the size of SST files in level-1.

target_file_size_multiplier - configures the size of SST files in further levels.

For eg : If target_file_size_base is set to 2MB and target_file_size_multiplier is 10,

Level-1 SST files will be 2MB,
Level-2 SST files will be 20MB,
Level-3 SST files will be 200MB and so on..

You can also configure the number of such files in each level using,
`max_bytes_for_level_base` and `max_bytes_for_level_multiplier`.

For eg : If max_bytes_for_level_base = 200MB and target_file_size_base = 2MB, then Level-1 will contain 100 files of 2MB each

You can check for these options in `options.h` and `advanced_options.h` files.

> if once it reaches that maximum size how files gets split in RocksDB

During compaction/flush, the files are created with configured size. If there are more files than the configured number, compaction gets triggered and the files are pushed to higher levels